Allowance modifier or technique?
Is there a modifier or a technique to add customizable allowance to selected geometry?
I can use the Shrink/Fatten modifier on selected faces, but this is a destructive operation. The possibility to control allowances is handy for 3D-printing where the printed parts often needs some iterations to fit well together.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143745/19307

Not a dumb solution for boolean diffferences, which I often need allowances for (screw holes for example)! Displacement modifier is almost a Shrink/Fatten modifier which I was looking for. I would be nicer though with a Shrink/Fatten modifier that works using length units. The Solidify modifier can work on vertex groups, so maybe we can do something like flip the normals of the generated inside mesh and ignore the outer mesh?
